# How do I hide a playlist window on my video?

Tags: css, video, playlist

Once I have the video uploaded, there is a playlist window that comes with it. In the image uploaded, I would like to keep the video (on the left) and hide the playlist window (on the right) but I am not sure how to achieve that.

CSS as below:

```
.is-mobile-layout .mobile-view {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
}
.grid-mobile-viewer .tile-wrapper.type-text .tile {
    min-height: 0!important;
}
/**********************************************
              FOOTER SETTINGS
**********************************************/
.footer {
  background: #2d2d2d;
}
/**********************************************
              HERO SECTION STYLE
**********************************************/
.hero-overlay:before {
  background: #000;
  opacity: .55;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.is-desktop-layout .twitter-embed .section-iframe-wrapper {
  padding-right: 50%;
}
```

I am unfamiliar with CSS...